# how to implement facebook phototheater kind of overlay?

Tags: jquery, overlay

hi i want a jquery over lay which works more like the facebook photo theater. i want to window scroll bars to scroll the overlay not the page below. how can that be achieved? i tried many jquery plugins none worked out..

Answer (score 0):

It's called a lightbox - search google for lots of plugins that work this way.  I used [pretty photo](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) some time ago and it worked great.

Comment: that looks cool.. but is there a way to disable scrolling the background if the overlay content is larger than the page?

Comment: I think I used the scale down functionality, so I don't know.